# Help with grammar, subjects and passives

Tags: grammar

> 明日…明日という日が遠い遠い先のことのように感じられた。

What does this mean?

My thoughts aren't really organised, so I'll just write down my thought process:

---

感じる can apparently be both:             [please correct this if wrong]

1 自（体が重く感じる : 体 as a subject that 感じる reflexively acts on） and

2 他（寒さを感じる : an unmentioned subject feels the cold ）

In the given sentence, I'm thinking that the conjugation of 感じられた is that of a 他 verb.

Following which, I'm thinking, something is getting 感じる'ed on.

Passive sentences have が・（は）to mark the thing getting 'ed on, right? So here, 明日…明日という日 should be the receiver (ie the subject) of the action of 感じられた, right?

In this case, is this interpretation correct? :

> The day called tomorrow was felt (by me) in the same way as a far destination.

ie

> （私に）[明日…明日という日が][遠い遠い先のことのように]感じられた。

Comment: 自発の「れる」って聞いたことあります？